# 難読化されたJavascriptの解読について

Tags: javascript, node.js

これは書かれていたものの一部なのですが、
これを解読するツールってありませんか？
解読できるウェブサイトなどはすでに試しましたが改行されただけで
解読はできないみたいでした
それとこれはnodejsで動作するプログラムのコードです

以下コードです

```
var jv = c(this, function() {
    var c = function() {
            return '\x64\x65\x76';
        },
        d = function() {
            return '\x77\x69\x6e\x64\x6f\x77';
        };
    var e = function() {
        var f = new RegExp('\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5c\x28\x5c\x29\x20\x2a\x7b\x5c\x77\x2b\x20\x2a\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x2e\x2b\x5b\x27\x7c\x22\x5d\x3b\x3f\x20\x2a\x7d');
        return !f['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](c['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67']());
    };
    var g = function() {
        var h = new RegExp('\x28\x5c\x5c\x5b\x78\x7c\x75\x5d\x28\x5c\x77\x29\x7b\x32\x2c\x34\x7d\x29\x2b');
        return h['\x74\x65\x73\x74'](d['\x74\x6f\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67']());
    };
    var i = function(j) {
        var k = ~-0x1 >> 0x1 + 0xff % 0x0;
        if (j['\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66']('\x69' === k)) {
            l(j);
        }
    };
    var l = function(m) {
        var n = ~-0x4 >> 0x1 + 0xff % 0x0;
        if (m['\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66']((!![] + '')[0x3]) !== n) {
            n(m);
        }
    };
    if (!e()) {
        if (!g()) {
            i('\x69\x6e\x64\u0435\x78\x4f\x66');
        } else {
            i('\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x4f\x66');
        }
    } else {
        i('\x69\x6e\x64\u0435\x78\x4f\x66');
    }
});
jv();
var y = 0x1f91;
const z = require('ws');
const A = require(b('0x0', 'k&7f'));
const B = require(b('0x1', '16E5'));
const C = require(b('0x2', 'KK1n'))(y);
const D = require('fs');
const E = require(b('0x3', '32fx'));
let F = 0x7d0;
```

Answer (score 1):

「解読」がどの程度のものを指すかわかりませんが、たとえば文字列リテラル内のhex表記(`\x77`)をデコードするようなことのできるツールならいろいろあるでしょう。（提示されているコードならこれだけでもかなり読めるようになるはず）

ex: [Online JavaScript beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) ([js-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify))
これの場合は 「 Unescape printable chars encoded as \xNN or \uNNNN? 」のオプション（npm/pythonパッケージの方であれば「unescape_strings」）を選択しておけば利用可能です。

得られたコード:

```
var jv = c(this, function() {
    var c = function() {
            return 'dev';
        },
        d = function() {
            return 'window';
        };
    var e = function() {
        var f = new RegExp('\\w+ *\\(\\) *{\\w+ *[\'|\"].+[\'|\"];? *}');
        return !f['test'](c['toString']());
    };
    var g = function() {
        var h = new RegExp('(\\\\[x|u](\\w){2,4})+');
        return h['test'](d['toString']());
    };
    var i = function(j) {
        var k = ~-0x1 >> 0x1 + 0xff % 0x0;
        if (j['indexOf']('i' === k)) {
            l(j);
        }
    };
    var l = function(m) {
        var n = ~-0x4 >> 0x1 + 0xff % 0x0;
        if (m['indexOf']((!![] + '')[0x3]) !== n) {
            n(m);
        }
    };
    if (!e()) {
        if (!g()) {
            i('indеxOf');
        } else {
            i('indexOf');
        }
    } else {
        i('indеxOf');
    }
});
jv();
var y = 0x1f91;
const z = require('ws');
const A = require(b('0x0', 'k&7f'));
const B = require(b('0x1', '16E5'));
const C = require(b('0x2', 'KK1n'))(y);
const D = require('fs');
const E = require(b('0x3', '32fx'));
let F = 0x7d0;
```

Comment: このようなものはどうすれば読めるでしょうか？



　var a = ['b8OFwoEaMw==', 'c0LDgxPDqkTDq8KSwr4nw63Dkw==', 'ICEZTQjCl8O5NsK0RsKvLw==', 'S8OOWMOUF2A=', 'W8KJW8OJNw==', 'TsKpPHF0', 'BxdDwq47', 'WMOAA8KbGg==', 'w6vDl8O2w7lH', 'w44cwqM=', 'wpdzN03DuURHwo/CqsOlchTDhg==',　・・・・

Comment: それ自体はbase64でエンコードされた文字列のようなので`atob()`とかでデコードは可能ですがそれだけの情報ではなにも分からないですね…… https://jsbin.com/zoqumicuhi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: なるほど！　でも文字化け（？）してるんでしょうか。。？　ほかのサイトでデコードしてみても同じように何が書いてあるか全くわからない文字がでてきました